# Lag a value based on criteria from list - python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I have a table that is formatted in the following format:

```
testdf = pd.DataFrame({"date":['2016-07-01','2016-07-02','2016-07-03','2016-07-04'],"freq": [10,15,20,13]})

testdf = testdf.set_index("date")

lst = ['2016-07-03', '2016-07-13']
```

I want to lag the freq value to the value prior if the index is in the lst (preferably with a pandas apply function).

Eg, in this example, the freq value for '2016-07-03' should be replaced with 15 as the date is in "lst" and so I want the prior day's value.

Appreciate any help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Use `pd.Index.isin` and `ffill`:

```
testdf.freq.mask(testdf.index.isin(lst)).ffill().to_frame()

            freq
date            
2016-07-01  10.0
2016-07-02  15.0
2016-07-03  15.0
2016-07-04  13.0
```